# ggplot2 – issue with overlay of lines and errorbars

Tags: r, ggplot2

On the same ggplot figure, I am trying to have the points (from `geom_point`), the lines (from `geom_line`) and the errorbars (from `geom_errorbar`) on the same "plane" (i.e. not overlapping), this for each factor.

As you can see the "layering" of the errorbars is not following the "layering" of the lines (not mentionning the points).

[image: points, lines and errorbars are not on the same "plane"]

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# reproducible example

# package
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# generate the data

set.seed(244)

d1 <-  data.frame(time_serie = as.factor(rep(rep(1:3, each = 6), 3)),
                  treatment = as.factor(rep(c("HIGH", "MEDIUM", "LOW"), each = 18)),
                  value = runif(54, 1, 10))

# create the error intervals

d2 <- d1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(time_serie,treatment) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(mean_value = mean(value), 
                   SE_value = sd(value/sqrt(length(value)))) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# plot 
p1 <- ggplot(aes(x = time_serie, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data=d2) 
p1
p1a <- p1 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.3), size =1) +
  geom_point(aes(), position = position_dodge(0.3), size = 3) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = treatment), position=position_dodge(0.3), size =1)
p1a
```

Any idea?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks a lot!
Valérian

Comment: ValZee, unfortunately the geoms are all layered by-geom, so the fact that you apply all errorbars first and then all points second and then all lines third is what is defining their z-layering. To me, the logical/intuitive method would be if there were an `aes(layer = ...)` aesthetic, but I don't think that exists. This question/example is a clear use-case to try to justify that argument to the `ggplot2` developers, in case you wanted to submit a feature-request (I have no idea how amenable they would be).

Comment: the first comment is correct. The geoms are layered in the order you call them. But maybe you can explain how you want the plot to look like? What do you mean by having everything on one layer? If a line and a errorbar cross, how do you want it to look like? One of the two will have to be on top, no?

Comment: @Mojoesque: you're right, when a line and an errorbar cross, one would have to be on the top. What I meant to say is if there is a way to get the lines and errorbars of a particular factor level on the same layer, so when lines and errorbars from different factor levels cross, the overlay will be consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up front: this is a *partial* answer that has two notable issues still to fix (see the end).  **Edit**: the two issues have been resolved, see the far bottom.

I'll change the "dodge" slightly to clarify the point, identify an area of concern, and demonstrate a suggested workaround.

```r
# generate the data
set.seed(244)
d1 <-  data.frame(time_serie = as.factor(rep(rep(1:3, each = 6), 3)),
                  treatment = as.factor(rep(c("HIGH", "MEDIUM", "LOW"), each = 18)),
                  value = runif(54, 1, 10))

# create the error intervals
d2 <- d1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(time_serie,treatment) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(mean_value = mean(value), 
                   SE_value = sd(value/sqrt(length(value)))) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(treatment)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# plot 
ggplot(aes(x = time_serie, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data=d2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.03), size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(), position = position_dodge(0.03), size = 3) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = treatment), position = position_dodge(0.03), size = 2)
```

[image: ggplot2 with mixed layering]

Namely, I'll assume that we want `HIGH` (red) points/lines/error-bars as the top-most layer, masked by nothing. We can see a clear violation of this in the right-most bar: the red dot is over the green errorbar but under the green line.

[image: zoom in to mixed layering]

Unless/until there is an `aes(layer=..)` aesthetic (there is not afaik), you need to add layers one `treatment` at a time. While one could hard-code this with nine geoms, you can automate this with `lapply`. Note that `ggplot(.) + list(geom1,geom2,geom3)` works just fine, even with nested lists.

I'll control the order of layers with `rev(levels(d2$treatment))`, assuming that you want `LOW` as the bottom-most layer (ergo added *first*). The order of geoms within the `list` is what defines their layers. Technically we still have a single treatment's errorbar, point, and line on different layers, but they are consecutive so appear to be the same.

```r
ggplot(aes(x = time_serie, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data=d2) +
  lapply(rev(levels(d2$treatment)), function(trtmnt) {
    list(
      geom_errorbar(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt),
                    aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value),
                    width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.03), size = 2),
        geom_point(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), aes(), position = position_dodge(0.03), size = 3),
        geom_line(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), position = position_dodge(0.03), size = 2)
    )
  })
```

[image: ggplot2 with layering fixed]

(Side note: I use `levels(d2$treatment)` and `data=~subset(., treatment==trtmnt)` here, but that's just one way to do it. Another would be `lapply(split(d2, d2$treatment), function(x) ...)` and use `data=x` in all of the inner geoms. This latter method allows for multi-variable grouping, if desired. I see no immediate advantage to one over the other.)

The problems with this:

1. The order of the legend is not consistent with the order of levels of the factor, somehow that is lost. (To be clear, I don't demonstrate this very well here: I can move "medium" to the middle of the legend using `levels<-`, and it works with the non-`lapply` rendering code with incorrect layering, but it is again lost with the `lapply`-geoms.)
2. `position_dodge` no longer has awareness of the other treatments, so it does not dodge the other errorbars. The only way around this (not demonstrated here) would be to *manually* dodge before plotting, shown below.

---

### 1: Order of legend elements

This one was solved in [lapply'd geoms lose factor-ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68863522/lapplyd-geoms-lose-factor-ordering), where we just need to add `scale_color_discrete(drop=FALSE)`.

### 2: Dodging

The `dodge` issue can be fixed by using real numerics in the `x` aesthetic. This is kind of a hack, as it is no longer done by `ggplot2` but controlled externally. It's also applying an offset and not dodging, per se. But it does get the desired results.

```r
d2$time_serie2 <- as.integer(as.character(d2$time_serie)) + as.numeric(d2$treatment)/10

ggplot(aes(x = time_serie2, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data = d2) +
  lapply(rev(levels(d2$treatment)), function(trtmnt) {
    list(
      geom_errorbar(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt),
                    aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value),
                    width = 0.2, size = 2),
        geom_point(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), aes(), size = 3),
        geom_line(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), size = 2)
    )
  }) +
  scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: everything fixed :-)]

Comment: ValZee, both issues have been resolved (losing legend order, and dodging). See the bottom of the edit for the final pieces.