# lapply'd geoms lose factor-ordering

Tags: r, ggplot2

In [ggplot2 – issue with overlay of lines and errorbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848999/ggplot2-issue-with-overlay-of-lines-and-errorbars/), I suggested an answer that used `lapply(.)` to produce groups of geoms in a particular order, so that points/lines/errorbars *for each level* would be layered together. However, it appears that the `factor` order of levels is lost in the process.

This first code block generates the original plot: the order of elements in the legend is correct (but the geom layering is not, this is before my answer).

```r
d2 <- structure(list(time_serie = c(1.3, 2.3, 3.3, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1), treatment = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("HIGH", "MEDIUM", "LOW"), class = "factor"), mean_value = c(2.93173234758433, 5.60600521659944, 7.85452806402463, 5.25617444992531, 3.6695183776319, 4.57195128872991, 3.24979097663891, 4.59766399173532, 4.39298335579224), SE_value = c(0.232090045905285, 0.585377662916667, 0.679289569404838, 1.3130008364543, 0.849157470954342, 1.22194305280708, 1.21458843275054, 1.0620028602709, 0.949469468240659 )), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = time_serie, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data = d2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value),
                width = 0.2, size = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(), size = 3) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = treatment), size = 2)
```

[image: ggplot2 with correct order of 'treatment']

The answer I suggested uses `lapply` to control the order of the layers. However, in doing so, the order of `treatment` levels is lost:

```r
ggplot(aes(x = time_serie, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data = d2) +
  lapply(rev(levels(d2$treatment)), function(trtmnt) {
    list(
      geom_errorbar(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt),
                    aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value),
                    width = 0.2, size = 2),
        geom_point(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), aes(), size = 3),
        geom_line(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), size = 2)
    )
  })
```

[image: ggplot2, order of levels is lost]

Note that the legend has the levels in the incorrect order.

```r
levels(d2$treatment)
# [1] "HIGH"   "MEDIUM" "LOW"
```

The answer to *"how to change legend element order"* is almost always *"use `factor(., levels=.)`"*, but that's been done and it is ignored.

Why is the order lost, and more importantly how can we retain the order in the legend (when layers are added as lists-of-geoms)?

*(PS: if you have comments on how to better control layering, please discuss it in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848999/ggplot2-issue-with-overlay-of-lines-and-errorbars/). This question is based on the requirement of using `lapply` for some reason to generate geoms, and therefore how to prevent that process from dropping factor levels. Thanks!)*

Comment: Hm. Not sure about the details. My guess would be that it has to do with argument `drop=TRUE` being the default for discrete scales. One option to keep the order in the legend would therefore be `ggplot(...) + scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE) + lapply(...)`

Comment: @stefan, that's it, write it up please! :-)

Comment: Done. Even if I would call it only a partial answer. (:

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but `drop=` in `scale_*_discrete` clearly (in my hindsight) says *"Should unused factor levels be omitted from the scale?"*. This makes sense in a way, since for each of the geoms within the `lapply`, the levels seen in any one layer are by design limited/reduced. Perhaps it's a small bug that this is determined at any one layer and not in aggregate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the details. So I would say this only a partial answer as it lacks a detailed explanation. But at least it offers a possible solution. My guess is that it has to do with argument `drop=TRUE` being the default for discrete scales. Hence, one option to keep the order in the legend would be to do `ggplot(...) + scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE) + lapply(...)`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aes(x = time_serie, y = mean_value, color = treatment, group = treatment), data = d2) +
  scale_color_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  lapply(rev(levels(d2$treatment)), function(trtmnt) {
    list(
      geom_errorbar(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt),
                    aes(ymin = mean_value - SE_value, ymax = mean_value + SE_value),
                    width = 0.2, size = 2),
      geom_point(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), aes(), size = 3),
      geom_line(data = ~ subset(., treatment == trtmnt), size = 2)
    )
  })
```

[image]